# Messaging in local network with .NET

Tags: c#

I need to implement some form of communication mechanism in my application, to send notifications/messages from one application instance to all the others. This is a normal scenario where someone adds and item or deletes and item and you want to notify other users that this has happened.

The application runs on the client and connects to a database on the local network. So its not like all clients access a server instance of the application. So from what I know I could use MessageQueues or some form of Database polling where I have a table that stores all the messages (not ideal).

Issue is I need to implement this very quickly, so sadly can't go very complex but need the quickest easiest solution.

thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like it might be easier for you to use optimistic concurrency.  Assume that things wont be deleted and deal with it at the affected client when it happens, which should be easier than developing some kind of concurrent notification system that won't scale at all...

Other than that, if you client list is small, db polling is the easiest way to do it without adding another layer of communication to your system, just add a table and implement a class library for everyone to do their thing on, if you can access the DB you are able to find out about deleted items etc.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about Optimistic concurrency, but that isn't an option for me as I need to notify users when a new item is inserted (within a couple of seconds of this happening). 

Adding a whole messaging layer isn't ideal, but would allow for me to use it extensively in the system. Issue is in my test app I'm getting MSMQ - Domain issues... so think polling it will be unless there's other options.

Comment: MSMQ is a dog.  The "right" way to do this is probably something like a publish/subscribe system, which you could roll yourself or find some libraries for.  I know that SQL Server Service Broker does have some multi notification features which might fit your purposes (it's a message queue in SQL, designed for stored procs to notify other entities that something has changed).

Comment: Well, MSMQ and all other options would have just taken too long, so implemented it already using polling. I just created a table, poll it every N seconds and then if there is a message in there for this user then read it and process it, then remove this message. And wherever need be, just create a message in the table for each user. When the user logs on, make sure to clear all messages so he doesn't get 100 messages when he logs in. Its all very basic, but works just like i need in our little system. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Rhino Queues should do the trick. Its a super-lightweight queue which doesn't need MSMQ and is XCOPY deployable

http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/03/rhino-queues-take-6.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You might like to check out my blog post [here](http://kentb.blogspot.com/2007/12/cab-event-broker-cross-process-events.html), which discusses a possible implementation of a cross-process event aggregator.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do this with WCF. It has a binding for peer to peer communications.

Answer (score 0):

I think polling the db is going to be your quickest route. Something real simple like, when a table has a modification made, store the time it happened in another table, using a trigger is one way to do this.

Your clients query that table and compare there locally held modified time, if the db time is newer then refresh.

Anything more than that would become complex..... especially with your 'couple of seconds' requirement.

You could implement all this in a way that could be replaced with more heavyweight method later if required.

Comment: Yeah, this is the route I ended up taking. As you say, as long as its done in a way that allows it to be extended its ok. But for now I can't foresee it needing to be anything more complex.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your network topology the natural choice would be to either a broadcast (same subnet) or multicast over multiple subnets when something new is added.
 Broadcasts are rather simple to program, but you need to check first if they are allowed in your network.

Answer (score -1):

You must first study Socket programming in C# open these links: 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10649/An-Introduction-to-Socket-Programming-in-NET-using

http://socketprogramming.blogspot.com/

next if u r a C# developer it will be easy to do so .

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.